# using OpenMPI to run for loops in c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmpi

I have a watered down code that I wrote in c++ . What it does is that it calculates array w,t, and the total time it took for the program to run. I have included the photo of what the output looks like below the code. the mean time is the mean of t array.

I wanted to parallelize the code using OpenMPI. I have started by initializing and getting proc ID and number of proc . I have searched online and watched youtube vids to learn the commands but I couldn't pick up anything about implementing for loop. I assume for the mean time and elapsed time I would use MPI send and receive? but for forloop I assume the processors should run the iterations individually and somehow collect it at the end ?

Been stuck with this for a while ... help

```
// number of iterations. Change accordingly 
int iteration = 10;

// Record start time
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// Toughness array
double w[iteration];

// Time array;
double time[iteration];

//time interval
double delta_t = 1e-6;

int main() {
    // Call MPI initialization
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get my processor ID and number of processor
    int myProcID;
    int numProcs;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myProcID);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProcs);

    for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++){

    ...
        if (...){
            w[i] = ...
            time[i] = ...
            t = ...
        }
t = t + delta_t;
}
    cout << setprecision(13)<< time_sum/iteration <<endl;

    cout << setw(20) << left << "Time"<< setw(10) << left << "Toughness" <<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
        cout<< setw(20) << left <<setprecision(13)<<time[i]<< setw(10) << left <<setprecision(13)<<w[i]<<endl;
    }

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish  - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
}
```

[image]

Comment: #High Performance Mark  Hi Mark, sorry about the confusion. I left out the calculations and load of if 's and else if 's which is used to calculate the array w. I left those out intentionally since I thought it wouldn't effect the parallelization ? as long as I can parallelize the "iteration" to begin with ? Also I thought I was supposed to use OpenMPI to implement this. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I should clarify. I am actually submitting this job to a supercomputer so  I should be using OpenMPI. If so how should I approach this Mark ?

Comment: assuming your iterations are independent from each other, you can replace `for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++)` with `int start = myProcID*iteration/numProcs; int end = (myProcID+1)*iteration/numProcs; for (int i = start; i < end; i++)`. at the end you might need to `MPI_Gather()` or `MPI_Reduce()` some data in order to print the results on rank `0`. without knowing your code and your efforts so far, it is impossible to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: #Gilles Gouaillardet Hi Gilles, each iterations are independent of one another. But I'm still curious as to the "start = myProcID*iteration/numProcs". If you do this wouldn't the indexes of the array w and time be  decimal?